# Traduciendo SQL en formato Eloquent

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Quisiera pasar el siguiente SQL de MySQL a formato Eloquent en un proyecto de Laravel (siendo 'lau' el término a buscar en la tabla de la base de datos y teniendo en cuenta el ID del usuario autor de los posts a filtrar en la búsqueda, en este caso, el usuario de ID igual a 12):

[SQL]

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = 12 AND (title LIKE '%lau%' OR slug LIKE '%lau%' OR description LIKE '%lau%')
```

He probado a poner esto en el método del controlador correspondiente:

```
public function profilePostsSearch(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = $request->user_id;
    $termino = $request->term;

    return Post::withTrashed()->where('user_id', $user_id)
                ////->with('comments')
                ->with(['comments' => function ($query) {
                    $query->withTrashed();
                }])
                ->where(DB::raw('LOWER(title)'), 'LIKE', "%".strtolower($termino)."%")
                ->orWhere(DB::raw('LOWER(slug)'), 'LIKE', "%".strtolower($termino)."%")
                ->orWhere(DB::raw('LOWER(description)'), 'LIKE', "%".strtolower($termino)."%")
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')//primero, por fecha DESC
                ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')//segundo, por ID DESC
                ->get();
}
```

El resultado no siempre es del todo correcto pues termina sacando resultados sin considerar el ID del usuario pasado.
Osea, a veces, saca resultados relativos a que cumplen que el término está contenido en los campos de `title` o `slug` o `description`, pero sin cumplir que el usuario sea el de ID igual a 12.

Es decir, lo que quiero es que considere siempre la parte del WHERE referido al campo `user_id` y luego las posibilidades o no del término en los demás campos. Y si no se especifica un término, es decir, si se pasa un término vacío, que el resultado de la búsqueda sean todos los posts de este usuario de ID igual a 12, siempre que tengan posts registrados claro está.

Nota extra: el SQL expuesto da el resultado deseado siempre y cuando ponga los paréntesis tras el `AND`. Si quito los paréntesis no resulta como se desea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que debes restringir los `orWhere()`, pues le estás diciendo `where(user_id ...)->orWhere(...)`. Prueba así:

```
Post::withTrashed()->where('user_id', $user_id)
                ->with(['comments' => function ($query) {
                    $query->withTrashed();
                }])
                ->where(function($query) use ($termino) {
                    $query->where(DB::raw('LOWER(title)'), 'LIKE', "%".strtolower($termino)."%")
                    ->orWhere(DB::raw('LOWER(slug)'), 'LIKE', "%".strtolower($termino)."%")
                    ->orWhere(DB::raw('LOWER(description)'), 'LIKE', "%".strtolower($termino)."%");
                })
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                ->get();
```

Hay un ejemplo muy parecido a lo que quiere en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#parameter-grouping)

Comment: Muy bien. Muchas gracias. Solamente, te falta poner el cierre del paréntesis del WHERE que incluye la function.

Comment: Ah, disculpa, se me pasó. Ahí lo agregué